# Unexpected undefined in function

Tags: javascript

My code output the position of every word in alphabet.

```js
function alphabetPosition(text) {
    const alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split("");
    const arrayFromText = text.toLowerCase().split("");
    alphabet.map((letter, position) => {
        if (arrayFromText.includes(letter) && alphabet.includes(letter)) {
            return position + 1;
        } 
    })
}
console.log(alphabetPosition('hello'));
```

Now it get `undefined`, but if i change to:

```js
function alphabetPosition(text) {
    const alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split("");
    const arrayFromText = text.toLowerCase().split("");
    alphabet.map((letter, position) => {
        if (arrayFromText.includes(letter) && alphabet.includes(letter)) {
            console.log(position + 1);
        } 
    })
}
console.log(alphabetPosition('hello'));
```

I get the expected result.
 *Why i get `undefined` in first example, and how to output the result using `return` statement, not `console.log`* ?

Comment: You don't return from the function

Answer (score 0):

### First Example

- `return` is returning from the function expression passed to `map`
- `return` is not returning from the `alphabetPosition` function, because the function returns nothing, your console statement will output `undefined`

### Second Example

- inside the `map` it's just outputting to the log
- having the `console.log` inside the `map` ensures the `position + 1` is defined, but note that it's not returning anything from that function
- because you have no `return` statement at the end of `alphabetPosition`, the function returns an `undefined`
- you have two `log` methods called, you should have seen the value of `position + 1` plus an `undefined` since the function returns nothing and you're still calling a `log` method

---

One way to make it work as expected is to return your mapping.  I added a filter to ignore all the `undefined` values in the array:

```js
function alphabetPosition(text) {
  const alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split("");
  const arrayFromText = text.toLowerCase().split("");
  return alphabet.map((letter, position) => {
    if (arrayFromText.includes(letter) && alphabet.includes(letter)) {
      return position + 1;
    }
  }).filter(v=>!!v)
}
console.log(alphabetPosition('hello'));
```